# Paste grep command in R

Tags: regex, r, paste

would like to paste the following line into R

```
awk 'match($0

paste("awk 'match(/)' testdata > out")
```

I get an error Error: unexpected input in "paste("grep "^\"

how would i paste it?

Comment: your example uses `paste("awk` but your Error output says `paste("grep`. Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cat("awk 'match($0, /^\\[[0-9]*\\]:/)' testdata > out")
```

The reason for the error is that `\` is considered a special character. So in order to escape it you need another backward slash before it. hence the double slashes `\\`.